# what's the `4161` modifier mean in java.lang.reflect.Method

Tags: java, reflection

i'm using java reflection to get method which are annotated with a specific Annotation . it returns two method , the one with modifier `4161` belongs to the interface . but i check the modifier specifications and can't find it anywhere ... help needed , tks :)

[image]

Comment: i didn't realise `4161` is a combination modifier and i've googled `4161`  no relative result found at all .  the duplicate you post is for those who have already know combination modifier .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `modifiers` integer is basically a combination of integer flags that form a bit field. You can use the static [`Modifier.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#toString(int)) method to get a textual representation. If you would use this method, it would tell you that `4161` stands for `public volatile`, and **it would be wrong**.

To break it down, the bit field represented by `4161` is composed of 3 integer flags: `1`, `64` and `4096`. Looking up these values in the [`Modifier` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.reflect.Modifier), it will tell you that `1` stands for `public` and `64` stands for `volatile`. Surprising, because methods cannot be declared as `volatile`, and what about `4096`? It's not even in the list!

The answer can be found in the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6), where we find that:

- `4096` (`0x1000`) indicates a *synthetic* method, i.e. a method that is not present in the source code.
- `64` (`0x0040`) not only represents the `volatile` access modifier, but can also be used to signify that a method is a *bridge* method, i.e. a method that is generated by the compiler.

The conclusion is then that a method with a `modifiers` value of `4161` is a `public` synthetic bridge method. This [article](https://javax0.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/syntethic-and-bridge-methods/) provides a fairly comprehensive overview.

Comment: The `public` bit is `0x0001` and the `volatile` bit is `0x0040`, so what's the other `0x1000` bit correspond to, where (`4161` is `0x1041`)? The greatest bit in the [modifier values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.reflect.Modifier.ABSTRACT) is only `0x0800`.

Comment: @Vulcan Appears to be a synthetic flag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540768/when-is-the-jvm-bytecode-access-modifier-flag-0x1000-hex-synthetic-set Will add to answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,  can you give a further explanation about `public volatile` , is this identify the `public` method in `Interface` ?

Comment: It's probably not a volatile method, but a bridge method. The value 0x40 is defined twice, once as `VOLATILE`, once as `BRIDGE`. See explanation [here](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2010/03/java-bridge-methods-explained.html). You could call `Method.isBridge()` to find out.